# Skip one iteration and adding conditions Python (Basic Question)

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, class, slice

I have been reading a text file a object and create a list with the contents.

textfile:

> ```
> Activity  Time  Location
> Football  8-9  Pitch
> Basketball  9-10  Gym
> Lunch  11-12  Home
> Read  13-14  Library
> Swim  14-15  Pool
> ```

```
openTime = 6
closeTime = 15
come = int(input('When do you want to come?'))
leave = int(input('When do you want to leave?'))

 # endtime_of_activity and startTimeofactivity is equal to the startingtime 
 # of each activity and the end time of each activity in the textfile 
 # (taken from a list that I have been splitting).

for i in range(len(my_list)):
    item = my_list[i]
    if (i == 1):
        continue
    if closeTime <= come <= endtime_of_activity and startTimeofactivity < leave <= closeTime:
        print(item.activities)
```

My question: As you can read in the textfile there are some activities appering on different times. For example football between 8 and 9. With the code I want to be able to skip the second element (basketball) as the code is doing, however, I want the if statement under "continue" to work. If i type that im coming 8 and leaving at 12 I want all the activities (excluding the second one) to show. This works for me when I'm doing a regular for-loop without skiping the second activity, like when im just writing: for i in my_list, then adding on the condition, but when Im doing the code above it shows me all the activites (except basketball) independeltly of when I chose to come and leave. What have I missed? How could I write the code better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to skip a certain activity, simply test if the activitiy to be printed is the same and skip it if it is:

```
with open("f.txt","w") as f: 
    f.write(("Activity  Time  Location\nFootball  8-9  "
            "Pitch\nBasketball  9-10  Gym\nLunch  11-12"
            "  Home\nRead  13-14  Library\nSwim  14-15"))
data = []
with open("f.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        act, time, what = (line.strip().split("  ") + ["","",""])[:3]
        if data:
            try:
                time=list(map(int, time.split("-")))
            except ValueError:
                continue # invalid time: skip row
        data.append([act,time,what])

header,*data = data 

openTime = 6
closeTime = 15
come = 9
leave = 12
skip=set(["Basketball"])

fmt = "{:<15}"*len(header)
print(fmt.format(*header))
for act,(start,stop),what in data:
    if act in skip:
        continue
    if start >= come and stop <= leave and openTime <= come and closeTime >= leave:
        print(fmt.format(act, f"{start}-{stop}", what))
```

Output:

```
Activity       Time           Location 
Football       8-9            Pitch          
Lunch          11-12          Home
```

Comment: Thank you! Are there no easier way to just skip one activity and doing what you did? For example is there no way to maybe slice? When Im doing: for i in my_list[1:], it works when adding the conditions, however, it skips wrong element of course. I want to do something like that but skip basketball then adding on conditions in a simple way if possible.

Comment: @Reza testing with conditions is better - if you want tio slice you would need to keep the input file fixed (so basketball has always come in the 2nd spot) etc.  - your  codes time comparisons were wrong - I fixed this in my approach. You can only participate in courses that stop after you come. closetime must also be bigger then the time you come (else you dont get admitted). your leave time must be after the activity started and stopped, etc...

Comment: @Reza You could filter your data like so:  `avail = [ [act,(start,stop),what] for act,(start,stop),what in data if start >= come and stop <= leave and act not in skip]` - untested. but thats just what the loop does (without printing it - you would need to do that on the filtered list)